# I can't see my ink levels for my canon pixma ip2702 printer

Tags: printing, canon, pixma

I have a canon pixma ip2702 inkjet printer, and cups doesn't show my ink levels, inkblot is
no longer available on the interwebs and mtink doesn’t seem to support my printer, I’ve 
checked my printer's website and none of the drivers support Linux so what do I do now?

Comment: That's the reason I bought HP this time around.  Canon make great products; shame about the terrible Linux support.  I had a Canon IP3300 previously - the driver worked well enough that it was OK, and I lifted the lid and looked at the blinkenlights to check ink levels. Now that it's dead I bought my SO a HP 1025nw laser printer and I'm impressed with the driver support and HPLIP utility.  (just a pain to get it installed and working wirelessly for my Ubuntu machine)

Answer (score 5):

There is a command line tool [ink](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/ink) [image: Install ink] reading ink levels from a variety of printers including Canon printers using **libinklevel5**.

- [List of supported printers](http://libinklevel.sourceforge.net/#supported).

Unfortunately the graphical tool [inkblot](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/inkblot) [image: Install inkblot] to display ink levels is deprecated and available for 10.04 **only**.

Answer (score 2):

After doing some serious digging I have found the solution to this for Canon Printers.  Mine is an MP495 but these two command are worth documenting.

1. cngpig -P
2. cngpigmonmp495 *****This one gives me my ink levels******  It is installed in the /usr/bin directory.

Answer (score 0):

some Canon printers can't show ink levels because they only have two cartridges.